# NHibernate console

Tags: .net, mysql, nhibernate, hibernate, hql

Looking for any kind of console where I could try my NHibernate HQL queries before encorporating them into my application. Something like MySql Workbench would be extremely nice to have: all I need is to type in a query and to receive the result back.

If possible, please list freeware tools first.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in these projects:

- [NHibernate Workbench](http://www.felicepollano.com/2010/05/19/NHibernateWorkbench.aspx)
- [HQL Language Service for Visual Studio](http://hqladdin.codeplex.com/)
- [NHibernate web console](https://github.com/mausch/NHWebConsole/wiki/)

Comment: Just tried NHibernate Workbench. It contains no help whatsoever, the errors returned boggle my mind. Its unclear how to proceed. Sure not as easy to use as MySQL workbench. @BreakPhreak What did you find useful as the best equivalent to a MySQL Workbench idea?

Comment: @MikedeKlerk of the projects I listed (over two years ago!) only NHibernate web console is being maintained (by me). Of course, you can always pick up the others where they were left off..

Comment: I like contribution to open source (=Picking up where they left of). But with a full time job, two kids < 2 years old I find I have little time to do any significant increments...

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I last used it, but I believe the [NHibernate Query Analyzer](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/NHibernateQueryAnalyzer) can do that, at least partly. YMMV.

Comment: Interesting. Downloaded. Got an exception right from the start without any option to continue. Sent the bug report. Waiting :)

Comment: Last update 2008, seems pretty dead to me. NHibernate support up to 2.1. All too bad...

Answer (score 0):

A dedicated tool would be nice but you don't really need it. You can test your queries using unit tests and NHProfiler. If you work on a team, you can share your tests so others will learn on it too.

Comment: But I think he's talking about being able to experiment with different queries, which unit testing won't really help with.

Comment: Exactly. I just need to try the queries for the start and see (later) how are they transformed into SQL queries as well. We do have unit/integration tests as well.

Comment: Debugging a unit test needs compilation, and loading lots of assemblies. If you quickly want to adjust and retest a query, unit testing is not suited.